# Mathrel in superscript

Tags: math-mode, relation-symbols

I would like to define mathematical relations that can also be used in superscripts. E.g. I would like to use

```
\newcommand\mesh{\mathrel{\#}}
```

both as `A\mesh B` and `A^\mesh`. The latter gives an error unless I write `A^{\mesh}`, but I would like not to have to remember to put the braces everywhere. Is this possible?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\mesh}{{\mathrel{\#}}}`. but I'm not at all sure why you'd want to put this in a superscript.  Is it that you want it to be positioned higher and smaller?

Comment: @barbarabeeton no: the braces would make a mathord, hiding the `\mathrel` for the superscript consider similar `A*B, C^{*}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Oh.  I missed the request to use `\mesh` both in-line and as a superscript.  (A visual example would have beat me over the head.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You *should* use braces, but you can declare `\mesh` as a mathchardef token not a macro using `\mathrel`

```
\documentclass{article}


\DeclareMathSymbol\mesh{\mathrel}{operators}{`\#}
\begin{document}

\[
a \mesh b + C^\mesh
\]

\end{document}
```