# \mathrel used in-line and in sub/superscript

Tags: symbols, math-operators, subscripts, superscripts, relation-symbols

I would like to define a `\mathrel` symbol composed of some text. For instance I would like to do something like

```
\DeclareMathSymbol\myrel{\mathrel}{???}{rel}
```

or perhaps another macro/custom symbol in place of "rel". Simply using `\mathrel{rel}` does not work however because I would also like to use it in subscripts and superscripts. I basically have the same issue as the post: [Mathrel in superscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655977/mathrel-in-superscript), except the answer doesn't work for me.

EDIT: apparently this is an old complaint... https://www.tug.org/twg/mfg/mail-html/1993-08/msg00076.html

Comment: The latex syntax is to always use braces with superscripts so there is no problem with `\newcommand\myrel{\mathrel{\mathrm{rel}}}`  as `x^{\myrel}` will work as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\DeclareMathSymbol` only to give a meaning to a character or a command so that a particular character is picked from the stated symbol font:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{<obj>}{<type>}{<symbol font>}{<slot>}
```

where `<obj>` is a character or a command name, `<type>` is `\mathord`, `\mathrel` and so on, `<symbol font>` a symbolic name for a math symbol font allocated with `\DeclareSymbolFont`; `<slot>` is a number, denoting the slot from the font containing the desired symbol.

You can define everything legal in math mode to be treated as a relation with `\newcommand` (or `\DeclareRobustCommand` if the object might end up in moving arguments):

```
\newcommand{\myrel}{\mathrel{???}}
```

And you can use `\myrel` in superscripts, of course:

```
A^{\myrel}
```

But `A^\myrel` will not work and there's essentially *no way* to make it to.

There's a reason why the LaTeX manual always braces subscripts and superscripts: because those works, whereas unbraced ones *may* not.

Comment: Technically, you could make `^` active and define it as a command taking one argument. Then `A^\myrel` would work. But you’re right: You *shouldn’t* do it.